# monitor power and lock screen (Ubuntu Lucid)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, xorg

I'm trying to get my screen to turn off whenever I lock my screen. I know that in Power Management, there's an option to turn off the screen after a set amount of time, and I know about `xset dpms force off`, but the former doesn't allow me to turn off the screen from the logout menu, and the latter only turns the screen off for a short amount of time (1 minute or so. The screen just turns back on by itself).

Is there a script I can modify to change what happens when "Lock screen" from the logout menu is selected, or is there a script I can add to the panel to lock the screen and then turn the monitor off (and turning it back on when I shake the mouse or something)?

Thanks.

Comment: In Ubuntu prior to 9.10, I had a script that did `gnome-screensaver-command --lock; xset dpms force off` and that actually worked.  But it doesn't anymore (same as you, monitor comes back on after 30 sec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
system 'sleep 1';
system 'xset dpms force off';
system 'gnome-screensaver-command -i &';
while(<>){`killall gnome-screensaver-command`;exit}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use vbetool (which requires lrmi)

```
vbetool dpms off
```

You could plug it into this following perl script (copied from gnomescreensaver.org and slighly modified for the event)

```
my $cmd = "dbus-monitor --session \"type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver',member='ActiveChanged'\"";

open (IN, "$cmd |");

while (<IN>) {
  if (m/^\s+boolean true/) {

       print "*** Session is idle ***\n";

  } elsif (m/^\s+boolean false/) {

       print "*** Session is no longer idle ***\n";

  }
}
```